# Add background image for collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Do anyone have idea to add the background image to the collectionview directly in storyboard and is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible 
I am using xcode 8.1 and it is possible in this version of xcode, I am not sure of other.
for XCode 8.1 i have tried and working as expected.

you just have to drag UIImageView on UICollectionView and its done.
Even it will automatically resize your UIImageView according to the size of your UICollectionView

Comment: happy it helped :)

Answer (score 12):

Better to do it programmatically creating a imageView like this

```
let imageView : UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named:"imagename")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()
```

and on the ViewDidLoad method

```
self.collectionView?.backgroundView = imageView
```

That'll make the background the image that you want

Answer (score 4):

This will work perfectly than the background color.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
    }
```